# VMware install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I downloaded VMware-Wokstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb and tried to install it on Ubuntu 14.04 by : 'sh VMware-Wokstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb' but I got the following result "sh: 0: Can't open VMware-Wokstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb".
Also I tried to install it by open the downloaded file with the software center but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you install a deb file. You need to use a package manager like gdebi or dpkg.

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg -i VMware-Wokstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi VMware-Wokstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb
```

Comment: Satellite-C850-B798:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Failed to open the software package
The package might be corrupted or you are not allowed to open the file. Check the permissions of the file.

Comment: Satellite-C850-B798:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb
dpkg-deb: error: `VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.deb